**Files Not Showing on Desktop GUI After Upgrading from Ubuntu 22.04 LTS to 24.04 LTS**
I recently upgraded from Ubuntu 22.04 LTS to Ubuntu 24.04 LTS, and after the upgrade, I noticed that the files previously visible on my desktop (home screen) are no longer showing up on the desktop GUI. However, these files are still present in the "Desktop" folder when accessed through the file manager.
I have tried restarting my system, but the issue persists. Is there a specific setting or configuration that might have changed during the upgrade? How can I make the files visible on the desktop GUI again?
I have uploaded screenshots showing the issue here: Google Drive link. After viewing the images, you will see that the folders/files are missing from the desktop GUI while still being present in the file manager.
Additional Details:

Ubuntu version: 24.04 LTS (upgraded from 22.04 LTS)
Desktop Environment: GNOME
Steps Tried: Restarting the system

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!
Thank you!

This question is similar to: Major software missing after 24.04.1 LTS upgrade. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Have you checked your xdg-user-dirs configuration (cat ~/.config/user-dirs.dirs)? Why did you ignore [Please specify if using GNOME, KDE, XFCE, etc.]? It could be relevant here (KDE in particular does things differently iirc)

@ArchismanPanigrahi I have uploaded screenshots showing the issue here: Google Drive link. After viewing the images, you will see that the folders/files are missing from the desktop GUI while still being present in the file manager.and this is just Small issue bigger issue is that i can't access my drive (Hard Disk)
